# Anime about a group of people sent on a quest by, I think, gods

Tags: story-identification, anime

If I remember correctly, each god selected a champion. I remember that one of the episodes was about helping a village before you could move on. Most characters only helped one person, claimed their reward and moved on. But one character helped the entire village and claimed the grand prize, before he moved on to help the rest of the adventurers.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this? Also, were the champions you mentioned regular humans summoned from Earth to a fantasy world? Or were they already native to the world the story is set in?

Comment: I dont remeber which year i watched it but I think they were all native to the world

Comment: We don't need the precise year, but it would be helpful if you could tell us the decade or range of years in which you would've seen this. For example, would it be the '80s? '90s? 2000s? 2010s?

Comment: I remeber watching it 2014-2017

Comment: I remember that after he claimed is prize for helping the entire village, he ran in the all of the other adventurers in a snowy mountains and they we corned by some large creature and he saved them all with the weapon he had received from the village prize.